# OData - Query for element in Collection

Tags: odata

I've created an OData server that exposes data in OData protocol V1 (max V2)

```
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="2.0">
```

Is it possible to perform an OData query by looking for a specific value in a collection?
I have this situation as example:

```
...
<entry>
  ...
  <d:Id>1</Id>
  <d:Attributes m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
    <m:item>A</m:item>
    <m:item>B</m:item>
  </d:Attributes>
</entry>
<entry>
  ...
  <d:Id>2</Id>
  <d:Attributes m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
    <m:item>A</m:item>
    <m:item>C</m:item>
  </d:Attributes>
</entry>
<entry>
  ...
  <d:Id>3</Id>
  <d:Attributes m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
    <m:item>E</m:item>
    <m:item>D</m:item>
    <m:item>F</m:item>
    <m:item>H</m:item>
  </d:Attributes>
</entry>
...
```

And I would like to show, for example, only the entries that contain the item `<m:item>A</m:item>`. How can I build the query?
Something like `...?$filter=substringof(A,Attributes)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use $filter=Attributes/any(d:d eq 'A')

For example:

```
http://odatasampleservices.azurewebsites.net/Experimental/DefaultService/People?$filter=Numbers/any(d:d eq '012')
```

Related Protocol: [Here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793848)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that my odata server doen't expose odata v4!
Is there a way to do something similar but with odata v1-3? (better v1-2)

Comment: @Marco any should be support from V3. for V1-V2...I have no idea. Maybe you can define a customer function to meet the requirement?

Comment: Yes, I see, but I'm using JayData for the server and for V3 not all the features are available. A custom function should definitely solve the problem but I have no clue of how to do it...